# Logging the Instance of runnable

Tags: java, android

I am not much experienced in java, but from what i know, a `Runnable` is just an interface which will enforce the class to implement `run()` function with some code, which would be executed in the calling thread.
I often like to use this functionality in a function like this:

```java
 public static void sleepAndRunOnUiThread(int millis,@NonNull Runnable action,@NonNull Activity activity) {
        Log.e(TAG, "sleepAndRunOnUiThread: recieved millis="+millis);
        Log.e(TAG, "sleepAndRunOnUiThread: recieved Runnable action="+action.toString());
        new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(millis);
                activity.runOnUiThread(action);

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }).start();

    }
```

A simple function that could be used to run stuff on ui thread after a delay. but is there a way to print the code lines in the given runnable `action`?

Comment: Java is a compiled language. The Java source lines are not in your compiled app, and so there is no means to print them.

Comment: @CommonsWare Oh okay,thanks for the info. Is there any other possible way (from the above params) for logging the details of the class from where this function is called?

Comment: You can create an instance of an exception (e.g., `new IllegalStateException("ick")`). You can then log the exception, or get access to the stack trace elements and work with them. Just bear in mind that if you are using ProGuard/D8 to obfuscate your code, your stack trace is also obfuscated.

Comment: What exactly do you _need_ to know and why?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen the above function is a part of my utility class, called by many other classes at different point of time. I wish to know which class is calling this function in my logs. a class name would suffice and i am guessing that me passing the activity instance would be enough to get such info (Not currently on laptop now, so can't check). Initially i was expecting to get the whole code of `Runnable action` in my logs but as commonsware pointed out, it isn't possible

Comment: So you want to improve logging on a method call.  Why not just do it in the actions themselves? (or learn aspect programming?).   Also, your interruptedexception handling is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @CommonsWare said, we cannot just print the source code as it is. and yes, i am now passing an instance of `IllegalStateException` for identifying the calling class (kind of a hack but works)

```java
 public static void sleepAndRunOnUiThread(int millis,@NonNull Runnable action,Exception eCaller,@NonNull Activity activity) {
        Log.e(TAG, "sleepAndRunOnUiThread: recieved millis="+millis);
        Log.e(TAG, "sleepAndRunOnUiThread: recieved Runnable action from ="+eCaller.getMessage()); // i pass description of action here
        new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(millis);
                activity.runOnUiThread(action);

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }).start();

    }
```